# Unity: How to make an array of video clips and play them?

Tags: unity, c#, video

I have 26 video files which I have to put in an array and play for different objects. So far I have written this from what I know:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;

public class videomanager : MonoBehaviour {

    public VideoClip[] vids;

    private VideoPlayer vp;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        vids = new VideoClip[25];
        vp = gameObject.GetComponent<VideoPlayer> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

I have attached this script on a plane on which I am playing the video.

Before that, I had 26 different planes, one for each different video, but I think it would be better if I could play them on a single plane and change the video according to logic.

I am not sure how I should load them into my player and play them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty simple application of the [`clip` property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer-clip.html) and [`Play()` method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer.Play.html) described in the [Unity VideoPlayer docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer.html).

Have you had any difficulty doing something like this?

```
// This script won't work without a VideoPlayer present,
// so let's ask Unity to enforce that relationship for us.
[RequireComponent(typeof(VideoPlayer))]

// The C# convention for class names is PascalCase.
public class VideoManager : MonoBehaviour {

    // Don't create/size the Array in Start() - that makes an empty
    // array, discarding the clips you assigned in the Inspector.
    public VideoClip[] vids = new VideoClip[26];

    private VideoPlayer vp;

    void Start () {
        vp = gameObject.GetComponent<VideoPlayer> ();
    }

    // Call this method when it's time to play a particular video.
    // Pass a number from 0 to 25 inclusive to choose which video.
    public PlayVideo(int id) {
        // To be safe, let's bounds-check the ID 
        // and throw a descriptive error to catch bugs.
        if(id < 0 || id >= vids.Length) {
            Debug.LogErrorFormat(
               "Cannot play video #{0}. The array contains {1} video(s)",
                                   id,                 vids.Length);
            return;
        }

        // If we get here, we know the ID is safe.
        // So we assign the (id+1)th entry of the vids array as our clip.
        vp.clip = vids[id];

        vp.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to do this where the videoclip is not assigned in the inspector in editor? i.e. from system.file.io.readallbytes?

Comment: @ina what do your tests so far tell you? If you're encountering an error, please post a new question about the specific place where you're stuck.